# Send client to cloudinary link upon button click

Tags: javascript, next.js, get, cloudinary

I'm using Next.js.  The cloudinary url that gets generated from cloudinary.uploader.upload... is result.secure_url in my app/page.js file.  The button code is in app/components/Cloudinary.js and is imported into app/page.js  I'm stuck on how to make the button click direct the user to the cloudinary url. I believe I have to make some sort of GET request such as below for the url.

```js
    import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
    
    export async function GET() {
      return NextResponse.json({ **unsure what would need to be in here** })
    }
```

Comment: Time has gone. Please select an answer or answer your question and select as resolved. This helps keep Stack Overflow tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want. Do you want to make a button submitting a get?

```
<button role="link" onClick={() => router.push("your-slug")}>
    Better use a link and style it like a button.
</Button>
```

Or use plain JS [Windows location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) for other (external, Cloudinary, ...) links.

Comment: When the user clicks on the button you have above I'm looking for it to go to http://res.cloudinary.com/do5l7hms7/raw/upload/v1708022067/........... which cloudinary stores in result.secure_url and the url is not constant.  My page.js file contains the website link that's created and I'm not sure how to get result.secure_url into the button which is in my Cloudinary.js file or if that's even possible. Basically sending it from page.js server side folder over to client side Cloudinary.js.

Comment: I still don't understand your explanation. If you like, provide a minimized version of your modules. If it is really Cloudinary-specific, probably I can't help.

Comment: I think I might have been off abt trying to use GET or routing.  Think what I needed was props. I was just trying to get CloudinaryButton.js to grab the URL by getting it from my page.js file.  This seems to work.. `import Link from 'next/link';
const CloudinaryButton = ({ excelUrl }) => {
  return (
    <Link legacyBehavior href={excelUrl}>
      <a>Download Excel File</a>
    </Link>
  );
};
export default CloudinaryButton;`  and page.js code ill post below.  You'll c below excelUrl is a fixed url but I need it to use result.secure_url which was generated when runScraper() was run.

Comment: `export default function Home({ searchParams }) {
   if(searchParams.runScraperButton) {
    console.log(searchParams);
    runScraper();  
 }
   return (
    <main>
      <RunScraperButton />
      <CloudinaryButton excelUrl='http://res.cloudinary.com/do5l7hms7/raw/upload/v1708022067/cjzrdfrtrodtwcityun2.xlsx' />   
    </main>
  )
}
const runScraper = async () => {...
}`  When I try to use excelUrl={result.secure_url}  I get an undefined error.

Comment: Sorry, can't help this way. Rethink your issue. Update your question with a clear description of what you want to achieve (not what you do). Minimize your approach and strip/mock Cloudinary, Excel and whatever away. If still not working, let's analyze your minimized and formatted code again.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  Looks like I got it to recognize the cloudinary result.secure_url variable by setting up a callback, or a promise works too.